# how to render partial view and image from same action result method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to return partial view and base64 string from same ActionResult method  on load of my View page.

This is my View:Index.cshtml

```
<body> 
<div id="topimage">
  @Html.Action("Fetch", "image", new { parameter = 1 }) //Seperate partial view to display top image.
<\div>


<div id="Bottomimage">
<img src=""/>//No partial View to display Bottom image here and how to call my controller method here with passing parameter.
<\div>
</body>
```

Partial View:**_TopImage.cshtml**

```
@model MyMvc.Demo.Model.ImageAttributes
  <div>
  <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image)" />
  </div>
```

**My Controller method which will display both Top and bottom image based on parameter 1 and 0**:

```
public ActionResult Fetch(int parameter)
   {
   using (var db = new MyDBContext())
      {
     if(parameter==1)//display top image
       var Image = db.ImageAttributes.Where(r => r.DisplayDirection == parameter).FirstOrDefault();
                return PartialView("_TopImage", Image );
      else 
       {
      var Image = db.ImageAttributes.Where(r => r.DisplayDirection == parameter).FirstOrDefault();
                    //Now here i just want to return Bytes of image which i will get in my ad Object as
                    //becasue there is no seperate partial view to display bottom image.so i will 
                    //direclty return bytes from here and convert in to base 64 sstring there to render bottom image
                    //for eg: <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image)" />
                    //How to do this
                }
            }
        }
```

Note:**I dont want to create Seperate Controller method and i dont want to change my any view**.

So can anybody please Guide me for this???

Comment: you have to call Action again in the bottom div

Comment: yeah but then how would i render image for my bottom image from controller side as because html.action returns action result

Comment: yes ofcourse it will

Comment: @EhsanSajjad:Can you please post your solution if possible

Comment: now if i use html.action again for bottom image then would i render my image ??

Answer (score 1):

You can store the action returned HtmlString in a variable if you dont want to call action two times:

```
@{
  var Image = Html.Action("Fetch", "image", new { parameter = 1 });
}
<div id="topimage">
   @Image //Seperate partial view to display top image.
<\div>


<div id="Bottomimage">
@image
<\div>
```

### UPDATE:

IN that case modify your action else part like this:

```
else 
{
  var Image = db.ImageAttributes.Where(r => r.DisplayDirection == parameter).FirstOrDefault();

  var base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(Image.Image);
  var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);

  return File(byteArray , "image/png", "image.png");

}
```

and in View:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Fetch", "image", new { parameter = 0 })" />
```

Comment: but then how would i pass 0 for bottom image??

Comment: if you want to show different image, then you have to call action again using ``Html.Action()`` in the bottom div, what i understood was you want to show same image in both div without calling action 2 times

Comment: Getting this error for bottom image:The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: Moreover this Url.Action wont call controller method.it will create path

Comment: @MariaPithia i have tested locally the above works fine

Comment: url.ACtion doesnt call controller.its just generate link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78389/discussion-between-maria-pithia-and-ehsan-sajjad).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load Your partial view to all it's View Page the simply call Your Partial View From Shared Folder of Your Views